# Is there a C++ API Linux System call that tells you which shared libraries your executable has linked?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I am wondering if anyone knows a C++ system call that produces output similar to the ldd command.  I am trying to get a list of all the shared libraries that the executable I am running has linked (just like ldd, but a C++ API). My end goal is to get the absolute paths of all the shared libraries my program has linked in.

Comment: I don't have an answer to this question, but I am inclined to ask _why_ you are looking for such a solution? Could this be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? You should provide what your reason is for needing this, since there might be a better solution for the problem itself, rather than the specific API you are requesting

Comment: Linux's `/proc` may be of use here, which your program could inspect while running.

Comment: Something like this? https://gitlab.com/miscripts/tldd/-/blob/master/tldd.cc

Comment: @dave Nice but won't handle `dlopen`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dl_iterate_phdr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <link.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int callback(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data) {
  printf("name=%s (%d segments)\n", info->dlpi_name, info->dlpi_phnum);
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  dl_iterate_phdr(callback, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

This program will produce the following output:

```
name= (9 segments)
name= (4 segments)
name=/lib64/libdl.so.2 (7 segments)
name=/lib64/libc.so.6 (10 segments)
name=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (7 segments)
```